# Optimalizations of SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm looking for some tips on optimalizing SSIS packages. I run a lot of them but the execution time is high. Some packages run on thousands or milions(2-15) of records. As the night time is not enough anymore they overlap and run 3-4 at once sometimes and that makes it even more difficult.
I did some testings.
I found that vievs are really bad in SSIS... They run faster when I run a SQL query and select into the view into a table and then go with the OleDB SOurce/Destination work.
As I look on the executions the source rows are selected in 5-10 min with over 5milin records but it takes 10 times more time to insert that data into destination table. As it goes I get this informations.

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Information: The buffer manager detected that the system was low on virtual memory, but was unable to swap out any buffers. 4 buffers were considered and 4 were locked. Either not enough memory is available to the pipeline because not enough is installed, other processes are using it, or too many buffers are locked.
> Information: Buffer manager allocated 0 megabyte(s) in 0 physical buffer(s).

Are there any options to make things move faster? Do I need to invrease DefaultBufferSize and DefaultBufferMaxRows at the same time? It goes on default 10k and 10mil.

Comment: It's very difficult to know what is the bottle neck without seeing the whole picture, but yes, increasing the buffer and max rows can help as long as the system has enough memory to allocate. Also, the buffer size and max rows may need to be relatively synchronised, otherwise the smaller will render useless the size of the larger. Another thing to consider and try to avoid are the asynchronous tasks, sort for instance, as these have to process all the rows before carrying on with the downstream tasks.

Comment: I see. Could you tell me the difference between Insert into on execute task and data flow task? The first one needed 10 min to complete the second 1h on the destination insert. AS I see the second one has a verification in it and the mapping is there also but anything else?

Comment: In the OLEDB destination Rows Per Batch and Maximum Commit Size can affect the performance. There is a good article about it here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1840/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-best-practices/

Comment: If you're wondering about performance differences between SSMS and SSIS probably check the value of `@@OPTIONS` between the two. At least `ARITHABORT` could be different and possibly other plan-affecting options as well. Set aside some time to read through Erland Sommarskog's [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html), especially _2.5 The Default Settings_ wrt. settings.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you, I will look at this.
One more question. Since I use a side database for report where I only restore the backup from PROD. Using TabLock is good? I mean normal selects lock the tables but this database is just for read. Would it be better for performance if I  would change the selects to no locks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes to get you going in the right direction:

- About this error below, this indicates that the server running your ssis packages ran out of memory.  As suggested, this could be caused because you have other processed consuming that memory, i.e. other packages running at the same time.

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Information: The buffer manager detected that the
> system was low on virtual memory, but was unable to swap out any
> buffers. 4 buffers were considered and 4 were locked. Either not
> enough memory is available to the pipeline because not enough is
> installed, other processes are using it, or too many buffers are
> locked.

- SSIS uses memory buffers to process data through a dataflow.  There will be a max of 5 used at any given time.  In this case, SSIS was unable to allocate the buffers needed to run the dataflow because there was not enough memory available.  Increasing the size of the memory buffer will only make things worse if the server is low on memory.
- Here's more details about how SSIS runs stuff so you can consider how memory is being used.  If you have multiple dataflows running in parallel in the same package, by default SSIS will run as many as the number of processors on your server +2.  So if you have 4 cores, you'll have 6 dataflows running at the same time.  In a dataflow, parallel execution is managed by the EngineThreads property.  The important thing to note here is just that the number of things that a data flow is doing between sources and transformations is limited.  So the less complex a dataflow, the more efficient it will run.
- What this means for you in a memory constrained system:

  - **Limit the number of packages running at the the same time**
  - **Limit the number of dataflows running concurrently in a package**
  - As a best practice, only have **one source and destination in a dataflow**
  - **Keep the dataflows simple.**  Use them to move data from one server to another.  Use SQL to do transformation work.  Use staging tables to land your data and then act on it before it is loaded into the final table.  Even if you are not doing any transformations, it will still be more efficient to load the table using SQL and a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause.
  - Once you've simplified the dataflow, but you are still seeing poor performance, **isolate the bottleneck**.  Run the dataflow with just the source and see how long it takes.  If that's slow, tune the source query.  Add subsequent tasks to the dataflow and measure the performance.  If you're only step that is slow is the destination, tune that.
  - **For tuning a destination**, try using a staging table with no indexes on it.  Use `TABLOCK` which will tell SQL to use minimal logging.  Once you've implemented the staging pattern, tune the SQL to load the data into the final table.
  - **For tuning the source**, avoid views because they may contain unnecessary joins and columns that you are not using, or use a view that is dedicated to your process so it can be written for exactly what you need.  A proc can be a better choice overall if there are a lot of tables involved - performance can be improved by using temp tables to stage data before joining it to the final largest table for the select.
  - **Do not use the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint in production.**  If the data is actually being updated at the time that you are reading it, you'd want your data to have those updates before you load it, nevermind phantom reads and the other terrible things that can happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this advices!

Comment: The packages are linear max 2 flows mostly 1 at time. The problem are huge views with milions of record like 30-50 mil. As far as I tested deleting them with sql and adding back is more efficient than update or there is a better way? I dont want to get always all data just most recend for a year. The final tables have some indexes created is it better to remove them? I use for staging the insert into command with tablock (before it was direct from view now it is more efficient as I tested). I have reads on 2nd PROD cluster but it locks the DB and dont sync with main PROD SQL, any ideas?

Comment: In the view there is probably one BIG table joined to others.  Separate out the BIG one into it's own dataflow.  Only get changed or recent rows if you have a way to figure that out.  Then doing updates from the staging table will be more efficient as it is handling fewer rows.  This is a better way to go than disabling indexes and rebuilding them as that will lock your target table.  All of this is easier to answer with more specifics -- pick one bottleneck and create another question with all the details - definition of the view and row counts if you can provide them.